# Javascript: How to find a given string in a URL?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 long URLs that point to the same page, 
http://preview.tbwabox.co.nz/_v005/index.html#buying-a-car
http://preview.tbwabox.co.nz/_v005/index.html#buying-a-house

and I would like to check if the URL has the string "buying-a-car" or "buying-a-house".

depending on the URL, it will show different default image in a carousel.

I tried,

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("buying-a-car") > -1) {
 alert("your url contains the name buying a car");
}
```

But it is not working

Comment: Why is it not working?

Comment: I have no idea? the if condition isn't firing.

Comment: I figured out, it is a very silly me problem. It is actually working. I am looking at the wrong place.

Comment: Yup, it has to work. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work
    `window.location.hash.substring(1)`
You can also use 
    `document.URL.split('#')[1]`